# Atom не сохраняет файлы

Tags: atom

собственно такая штука, при открытии папки с проектом java через ПКМ-Открыть с помощью Atom, не сохраняет файлы, при этом если проект добавлять в уже открытый Атом, то все нормально. Но можно ли как то это исправить, что бы сохранял и при открытии через ПКМ тоже?

Comment: Ошибки какие-нибудь выдаёт?

Comment: @timur Нет, вообще ничего, просто не сохраняет, разве что нажать ctrl+S, выйти из атома и зайти обратно, вот тогда он все сохранит, но это маразм)

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в пакете ide-java, там надо было ставить через git, а не через меню